# locust bad argument to internal function

Tags: python, locust

I am trying out a locust [tutorial](https://blog.realkinetic.com/load-testing-with-locust-part-1-174040afdf23).

I am having an error `Objects/dictobject.c:1439: bad argument to internal function` when I am trying to run `locust -f locustfile.py --host=http://localhost:8080` .

Server is running already.

Error snippet:

```
...
[2018-07-25 08:55:06,330] CRMs-iMac/INFO/locust.main: Starting web monitor at *:8089
[2018-07-25 08:55:06,330] CRMs-iMac/ERROR/stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
[2018-07-25 08:55:06,330] CRMs-iMac/ERROR/stderr: File "/Users/crmonlinegraph/.virtualenvs/venvpy3.7/bin/locust", line 11, in <module>
[2018-07-25 08:55:06,331] CRMs-iMac/ERROR/stderr:
[2018-07-25 08:55:06,331] CRMs-iMac/ERROR/stderr: sys.exit(main())
[2018-07-25 08:55:06,331] CRMs-iMac/ERROR/stderr:
[2018-07-25 08:55:06,331] CRMs-iMac/ERROR/stderr: File "/Users/crmonlinegraph/.virtualenvs/venvpy3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/locust/main.py", line 430, in main
[2018-07-25 08:55:06,331] CRMs-iMac/ERROR/stderr:
[2018-07-25 08:55:06,331] CRMs-iMac/ERROR/stderr: main_greenlet = gevent.spawn(web.start, locust_classes, options)
[2018-07-25 08:55:06,331] CRMs-iMac/ERROR/stderr:
[2018-07-25 08:55:06,331] CRMs-iMac/ERROR/stderr: File "src/gevent/greenlet.py", line 538, in gevent._greenlet.Greenlet.spawn
[2018-07-25 08:55:06,332] CRMs-iMac/ERROR/stderr: File "src/gevent/greenlet.py", line 213, in gevent._greenlet.Greenlet.__init__
[2018-07-25 08:55:06,332] CRMs-iMac/ERROR/stderr: File "src/gevent/_hub_local.py", line 80, in gevent.__hub_local.get_hub_noargs
[2018-07-25 08:55:06,332] CRMs-iMac/ERROR/stderr: File "/Users/crmonlinegraph/.virtualenvs/venvpy3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 390, in __init__
[2018-07-25 08:55:06,332] CRMs-iMac/ERROR/stderr:
[2018-07-25 08:55:06,332] CRMs-iMac/ERROR/stderr: WaitOperationsGreenlet.__init__(self, None, None)
[2018-07-25 08:55:06,332] CRMs-iMac/ERROR/stderr:
[2018-07-25 08:55:06,333] CRMs-iMac/ERROR/stderr: File "src/gevent/_greenlet_primitives.py", line 42, in gevent.__greenlet_primitives.TrackedRawGreenlet.__init__
[2018-07-25 08:55:06,333] CRMs-iMac/ERROR/stderr: SystemError
[2018-07-25 08:55:06,333] CRMs-iMac/ERROR/stderr: :
[2018-07-25 08:55:06,333] CRMs-iMac/ERROR/stderr: Objects/dictobject.c:1439: bad argument to internal function
[2018-07-25 08:55:06,333] CRMs-iMac/ERROR/stderr:
```

locustfile.py:

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task

class UserBehavior(TaskSet):
    def on_start(self):
        """ on_start is called when a Locust start before any task is scheduled """
        self.login()

    def on_stop(self):
        """ on_stop is called when the TaskSet is stopping """
        self.logout()

    def login(self):
        self.client.post("/login", {"username":"ellen_key", "password":"education"})

    def logout(self):
        self.client.post("/logout", {"username":"ellen_key", "password":"education"})

    @task(2)
    def index(self):
        self.client.get("/")

    @task(1)
    def profile(self):
        self.client.get("/profile")

class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = UserBehavior
    min_wait = 5000
    max_wait = 9000
```

The only `dictobject` would be `{"username":"ellen_key", "password":"education"}`. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Locust is not yet compatible with Python 3.7... downgrade to Python 2.7 or 3.6.  Also, you can file an issue for this here: https://github.com/locustio/locust/issues

Comment: @Corey, works on Python 2.7. Thanks for the input mate!